# How to show icon inside a taskbar menuitem

Tags: c#

I want to have a similiar menu in my taskbar icon. Actually I have there some menuItems. But how can I achieve, that a clicked menuItem is marked with icon as shown in the picture?

[image]

I defined my menu like this, this one I want to mark with another icon

```
//initialize EMAIL
        this.menuItemEmail.Index = 4;
        this.menuItemEmail.Text = Resources.EMAIL;
        this.menuItemEmail.Click += new   System.EventHandler(this.email_changeAction);
```

Comment: Sometimes its too easy. There is a Checked Property which enables this. in my case this.menuItemEmail.Checked = true; showed the marker

Comment: ..and how can you show an arbitrary icon?